# Transforms on WriteableBitmap

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I'm writing app in WP7 mango and try to transform image loaded from binded to WriteableBitmap in XAML for example like this:

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Image Source="{Binding SourceImage}">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding RotateAngle}"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

I bind Angle with my property Angle in my ViewModel, i change from slider this value but image doesn't rotate. Raising property changed is working correct. 
When i do it with image loaded from contets file, static image, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really weird. I have yet to understand where the problem comes from, but you can get around using Projection instead of RenderTransform:

```
<Grid>
   <ScrollViewer>
       <Image Source="{Binding SourceImage}">
           <Image.Projection>
               <PlaneProjection RotationZ="{Binding RotateAngle}" />
           </Image.Projection>
       </Image>
   </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

**Edit:**

Ok, actually it seems the problem comes from the ScrollViewer rather than the Image. Set the RotateTransform directly on the ScrollViewer and it should work:

```
<Grid>
   <ScrollViewer>
       <ScrollViewer.RenderTransform>
           <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding RotateAngle}" />
       </ScrollViewer.RenderTransform>
       <Image Source="{Binding SourceImage}" />
   </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Or put the Image inside a Grid inside the ScrollPanel:

```
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Image Source="{Binding SourceImage}">
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding RotateAngle}" />
                </Image.RenderTransform>
            </Image>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

But I'm still clueless about why this happens.

**Edit 2:**

Ok I found the bug. It has been introduced in the last WP7 builds. Basically, the scrollviewer will overwrite the RenderTransform of its child if it's different than its own. 
So you have three solutions:

- Define the RenderTransform directly on the ScrollViewer
- Wrap your child element in a dummy container element. This way, the dummy element's rendertransform get overwrited and not yours:
- At initialization, replace the ScrollViewer's RotateTransform with the element's:

  ```
  public MainPage()
  {
      this.InitializeComponent();

      this.ScrollViewer.RenderTransform = this.Image.RenderTransform;
  }
  ```

I would personnaly go with the first or second solution. I fear there could be unexpected side effects with the third solution.

Comment: Thank you very much! I chose way with put the Image inside a Grid inside the ScrollPanel. It works great

Comment: You should also start accepting answers. With 0% answer rate, people will soon stop answering you...